# What weapons should a pain transferring super hero use

Tags: weapons, super-powers

I'm creating a sci-fi story and one of my main characters has the ability to transfer her sensations to a target. This makes her difficult to fight in hand to hand combat since you would feel the blow from every punch you deal.

However, she can only transfer the sensation of pain to her enemies, she still receives any damage she takes, but simply doesn't feel it while her power is turned on.

All she can transfer is the feeling of pain. She will still receive the physical reactions to whatever element she uses.

What kind of weapon should she use to fight generic ordinary Joes?

I was thinking of something she could use on herself to cause debilitating pain, but not actually cause any damage to herself.

What kind of weapon or tool would be best for that?

Would a different strategy or weapon be better suited for her abilities? (Like say a sword or gun with poison ivy on the handle)

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have the time please [take the tour](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [visit the help center](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: How exactly is the pain transferred? If something affects nervous system, it gets transferred to other person? Does this include electroshocks and chemicals? If it includes chemicals, then your Heroine could simply inject herself with botox (botulinum toxin which paralyses neurons) and transfer paralysis to others, casing death through respiratory failure. If Heroine zaps herself with tazer, will her nervous system get overloaded? Will she spasm or all effects will be transferred?

Comment: She receives all the effects, but the signals to her brain that deciphers the signals into touch and pain kinda get unplugged. Enemy then feels what she should have felt. They don't receive any effects other than the touch or pain sensation. If zapped with a teaser she WILL spasm but it won't hurt

Comment: I see. Then I certainly DON'T have better ideas than capsaicin answer. Not unless you include non-existent devices like Dune's [Nerve induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_induction)

Comment: One problem with pepper spray though is that she'd have to wash it off before she turned her power back off. And if she missed a spot it'll hurt pretty bad

Comment: @DalbyBrynn It's fat soluble. You can wash it off with a carton of milk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A suit that is covered with electrodes on the inside.

The electrodes can be setup to stimulate the various nerve clusters that are known in martial arts as pressure points.

There are clusters behind the elbow, in the junction between thumb and forefinger, between the nose and upper lip, behind the ear, in the hollow of the throat, and the solar plexus, just to name a few.  accurate and even somewhat gentle strikes to these points can be nearly debilitating from a pain standpoint, but generally don't cause any side effects you might see with pepper spray or a taser or stun gun (muscle spasms).

Stimulating the point in the hand would make it difficult for the victim to hold a weapon, to many of the other points the pain makes you want to get away from the source, but it's not a reflexive action that your heroine would have to deal with.

Use the power to distract your opponent to allow you to strike with a more conventional weapon.

fun stuff

Comment: I really like this suggestion. It takes good advantage of her powers and doesn't cause any actual harm to her.

Comment: Thanks, you can probably get more detailed information just by googling martial arts pressure points.  You could do some groovy stuff if you look into accupressure and give her the ability to be the ultimate psychic massuese too... :)

Comment: Call her, *The Maiden*. This suit is a real step-up from what she had to wear in the 14th century.

Answer (score 6):

[Capsaicin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsaicin) or other [pepper spray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_spray). Capsaicin works by triggering the sensory neurons associated with sensing heat and physical abrasion. The inflammation associated with exposure is a result of our physiological response to the sensation, not a chemical response to the Capsaicin.

Your hero will cause a lot of pain to their adversaries without injuring themselves. One of the disadvantages of aerosolized compounds is that there is always the risk of self exposure due to the direction of the wind. Since your hero won't feel the effects while transferring sensations of pain this will improve their efficacy.

Comment: I don't think this would work. If damage happens, then physical reaction happen too. Heroine might not feel pain from pepper spray, but she won't see anything through the tears anyway.

Comment: There is no injury caused by exposure to capsaicin. This is why it's such a popular self defense weapon, no injury to bystanders.

Comment: M i ech is correct. She won't get hurt my the pepper spray, but she would still be physically affected. Editing post to reflect this

Comment: To quote wikipedia "capsaicin does not actually cause a chemical burn, or indeed any direct tissue damage at all, when chili peppers are the source of exposure. The inflammation resulting from exposure to capsaicin is believed to be the result of the body's reaction to nerve excitement"

Comment: I see. So you say that all the swelling, tears and general reaction of mucous membranes is actually caused by nervous system and not (as I assumed) reaction of mucous membranes themselves. If that's true, then I retract my objection.

Comment: Oh wow TIL. I thought it was a chemical reaction too my b.